# Opentok not calling the controller methods (sessiondidconnect) in ios

Tags: ios, codenameone, opentok

I am trying to implement an OpenTok application using codename one. I already started with android and had pretty much everything working. I use a native interface to import the OpenTok library.

Now I am trying to implement the ios side. I have a class acting like the view controller :

```
@interface be_lsit_opentok_iosTestHelper <OTSessionDelegate, OTPublisherDelegate> : NSObject
```

This class implements all the needed methods for the session connection : https://tokbox.com/developer/tutorials/ios/basic-video-chat/ (step 4).

My class implementing the native interface handles the initialization of the session with the api_key... and then calls the session's "connectWithToken".

Once this is done I can notice using the OpenTok Playground that the connection works but I do also notice that opentok does not send a message to call the method "sessionDidConnect" which is a problem.

I do not understand why the call is not done and what sould I do?

I also tryed to call the method myself using a thread call the method only when the connection to the session is made and that its status is "OTSessionConnectionStatusConnected" and this worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing here since I didn't do this. You implemented the `viewDidLoad` in your own code instead of the Codename One view did load.

You can inject code into the Codename One `viewDidLoad` method using the build hint `ios.viewDidLoad`. So a build hint like:

```
ios.viewDidLoad=[self connectToAnOpenTokSession];
```

Should work but you would also need to add an import for the API into our code. Unfortunately I couldn't find a suitable build hint to define that so I added one `ios.viewDidLoadInclude` which I will add tomorrow to the build will allow you to define an import or include statement required by the statement above.

Comment: How should I use the new build hint? just add it but I don't know what to make as value? Thank you :)

Comment: `ios.viewDidLoadInclude=#import "pathToOpenTokHeaderThatYouNeed"`